How to delete across multiple collections using a query in Mongo?
I have a requirement where I want to delete across multiple collections in a database using a query. For example, let’s say “id”. I want to delete all the documents in all the collections that I have in my database which has the “id” field with value “123” for example. And this should be from a code, let’s say a Go code.
I tried reading through different documents and Stack Overflow questions but I couldn’t able to find an answer. Currently I’m running a loop to do this, but this will be multiple calls to DB. How can I do it in a single call?

That is the reason why you should not scatter documents across collections if they are meant to be queried together. For your current scenario, try to use bulk operation to group together the calls.

But the issue is, they are stored in different collections to mean they are for different purposes, this bulk delete is done to remove everything that is part of an “operator” per se. The bulk write is done for a single collection though.

Could you expand on why deleting them individually would not be a good solution? How many might you have to do in one go?
